# Calculate R2 score of a fitted polynomial regression curve whereby one x point has multiple y-true values

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, polynomial

How do I calulate the R2 score of a fitted polynomial regression curve whereby one x point has multiple true y-values?

The sklearn r`2_score(ytrue, ypred)` method fails with this error because i have 13 ypred points, but 48 ytrue points

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [48, 13]

Is my concept of fitting a polynomial regression in such a manner wrong? The reason why there are multiple ytrue points for the same x-point is because they are each contributed by a different Id (eg. person)

Should i not lump the data points of each person to the plotting space? And rather fit a curve for each person instead, and then aggregate the coefficients (ie. sum all the polynomial coeffs and divide by the number of people).

Answer (score 1):

For each prediction in `ypred` you need to enter the true value in `ytrue`. So you need to repeat the values in `ytrue` so that they are properly paired with the values in `ypred`.